# JSSOR image slider - add local video

Tags: video, html5-video, jssor

I want to add a video player to my JSSOR image slider.
But I need to play a local video, and not a youtube or vimeo video.

Has somebody some experience with it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add everything you like to any slide in the slider.

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    <div>
        <!-- add your html5 video here, better to specify style="position: absolute; top: ...px; left: ...px; width: ...px; height: ...px;" -->
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```